# TABLA MYSQL - No muestra el contenido

Tags: mysql

[image]

En esta base de datos tengo 3 tablas. Hoy todas estas tablas funcionaron perfectamente pero de repente la tabla "sistema" dejó de mostrar su contenido aqui en PhpMyAdmin y en la página PHP también. Las otras 2 tablas funcionan perfectamente, solamente esta tabla "sistema" es la que esta teniendo este problema. Busqué en Google y: la opción -reparar tabla- de PhpMyAdmin no funcionó. ¿Qué puede estar causando este problema y cómo puedo solucionarlo? Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: REiniciaste la base a ver si se arregla? no borraste los datos sin querer?

Comment: Reinicié y nada, no se arregla.

Comment: Aunque yo haya borrado los datos sin querer, (lo cual no es así) aún me mostraría las otras informaciones que muestra phpMyAdmin de 1 tabla

Comment: ok entonces esperemos a algun experto en mysql

Comment: La última imagen parece indicar que: la tabla se creó el 9 de marzo; por su tamaño y el próximo auto incremental establecido en 0 no tiene datos. Sería interesante revisar los log de la base de datos y/o de PHP en busca de alguna respuesta. Por ejemplo, si es una base de datos expuesta públicamente y tienes código vulnerable, te pueden borrar la tabla por medio de *Inyección SQL*. Si no tienes una política de backups establecida es tiempo de ir pensando en ello.

Comment: Cómo puedo revisar los log de la base de datos y/o de PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

el problema sucede porque quieres mostrar mas elementos de los permitidos por PhpMyAdmin, lo que debes hacer es ir a configuración (el engranaje justo por debajo del logo de PhpMyAdmin) y cambiar estos dos parametros:
Cantidad máxima de elementos en el primer nivel
Número mínimo de elementos para mostrar la caja de filtro
los valores dependeran de cuantos elementos que quieras mostrar.